# Web Services: WCF or Python based services

Tags: performance, wcf, web-services, flask

**Task:** We are looking to develop a WebService that basically performs certain management operations on files such as indexing, compression, streaming. the file can be anything from text to images to video and we manage it all.

**Problem:** After the architectural discussion we decided to choose the programming platform. Now personally i am comfortable with WCF Services and have had my share of experience with them and played with them enough. But the other developers on my team are leaning more towards python and are looking to base the service off **Flask** or **Bottle**

Now i have tried searching for differences but all i find is how to implement WCF using IronPython. Language is not a problem as we all learn it and we have time to spend but what is important is that we get it right. **Speed** and **Reliability** is of the utmost importance and so I just need some advice or may be a few benchmarks to show which direction is the best.

**Additional Info:** we'll be hosting the service on AWS so we've got good enough hardware requirements and are not affected by lack of scalability. Also db will divided between NoSql and RelationalDB.

Comment: Which one is easier to work with? Python may be nice, but it might not have a few libraries that significantly reduce your development workload if you were to choose WCF. Aside from that, if you're going to be deploying on Windows, I would first benchmark how well Python webapps perform on it.

Comment: @Blender: Actually if we are go the python route then i wouldn't pick Windows as my operating system. So i don't know if the python benchmark will be accurate in that scenario. In any case i am developing the python flask service as we speak (that explains my delay in response) but the only difference i see as of now is the initialization time. WCF takes time to kick in while python goes up and running easy. But i have no clue how i am going to simulate a lot of users using the service? any way to do a stress test??